# How to correctly use getline?

Tags: c, getline

I was trying to use getline for user input and I manage to do so but each time I try to print everything after %s (like .) it gets put to the next line and I am also trying to get rid of trailing space characters input so I use the function below but for some reason this isn't working, any help, sorry for anything improper still learning:

Also can I print the contents of buff like an ordinary array (for loop) or is it different if I use getline?

```
/******************************************************************************



*******************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int trim (char *s)
{
    int i = strlen(s) - 1;
    while (i > 0){
        if (s[i] == ' '|| s[i] == '0'){
            i--;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    s[i + 1] = '\0';
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return (strlen(s)); 
    
}

int main()
{
    char *buff = NULL;
    size_t sizeAllocated = 0;
    printf("Begining!!\n");
    printf("> ");
    size_t numCh = getline(&buff, &sizeAllocated, stdin);
    //numCh = trim(buff);
    printf("%s.", buff);
    
    free (buff);
    buff = NULL;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Change `if (s[i] == ' '|| s[i] == '0')` to `if (s[i] == ' '|| s[i] == '\n')`. The `getline` function puts the newline character `'\n'` at the end of the line, followed by the NUL terminator `'\0'`. It's the newline that you need to remove from the buffer.

Comment: Or simply `buff[strcspn (buff, "\n")] = 0;` will trim the trailing `'\n'` in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems:

`numCh` must be a `ssize_t`, which is the preferred type to handle errors on POSIX, use it :)

Always check the result of `getline`

`int i = strlen(s) - 1;` is very prone to errors because `strlen` returns an `unsigned` (`size_t`) and an empty string will give you a very big number (`SIZE_MAX`).

Check if this helps:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

static char *trim(char *str)
{
    while (*str && isspace((unsigned char)*str))
    {
        str++;
    }
    if (*str)
    {
        // Here it is safe to use `strlen - 1` because
        // `if (*str)` ensures that there is a character
        char *end = str + strlen(str) - 1;

        while (*end && isspace((unsigned char)*end))
        {
            end--;
        }
        *(end + 1) = '\0';
    }
    return str;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    ssize_t len = 0;

    if ((len = getline(&str, &size, stdin)) != -1)
    {
        const char *trimmed = trim(str);

        printf("<%s>\n", trimmed); // Use trimmed
    }
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With `while (*str && isspace((unsigned char)*str))`, under what contion do you see `*str` is false?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it can be translated to while there is a character different to zero and this character is not an empty (newline tab or space) character, do you see anything wrong? is not very well tested :)

Comment: OK.............   (`while (*end && isspace((unsigned char)*end))`) is only a problem when `char` is _signed_ and not 2/s complement, something not important these days.))

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the other very good answers, you have a type issue with `numCh` which is technically a POSIX type `ssize_t`. (one drawback of `getline()` if needing to port to systems that don't support POSIX -- thankfully, other than a few embedded systems, almost all do)

The other issue is automatically checking `strlen(s) - 1` where `strlen(s)` can very likely be `0` if there is no `'\n'` to read.

In addition to the other approaches, since you already include `string.h` the function `strcspn()` provides a convenient way to locate the `'\n'` at the end of the string -- returning the number of characters up to the `'\n'` (if present) -- eliminating the issue of blindly subtracting `strlen(s) - 1` potentially resulting in a negative value.

Using `strcspn()` your `trim()` function can be written as:

```c
size_t trim (char *s)
{
    size_t len;   /* length of s after trailing whitespace trimmed */
    
    s[(len = strcspn (s, "\n"))] = 0;   /* trim \n saving length */
    
    /* trim remaining whitespace */
    while (len && isspace ((unsigned char)s[len - 1])) {
        len--;
    }
    s[len] = 0;   /* nul-terminate at len */
    
    return len;   /* return new len */
}
```

(**note:** all `ctype.h` classification function require the parameter be `unsigned char`. While this is virtually guaranteed if reading ASCII from `stdin`, the pedantic approach is a cast to the proper type)

Additional notes:

1. you only need one output function for any continual block of text, not one `printf()` for each line. Additionally, if there are no conversions involved, then `fputs()` is fine -- though a good optimizing compiler should make the substitution for you,
2. ALWAYS validate each user-input by checking the return of whatever input function you are using to determine whether the input *succeeded* or *failed*. Blindly assuming your input is good tempts *Undefined Behavior*,
3. printing `buff` before and after `trim()` along with the length provides a convenient visual way of confirming the behavior your want.

Putting the pieces together, you could do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

size_t trim (char *s)
{
    size_t len;   /* length of s after trailing whitespace trimmed */
    
    s[(len = strcspn (s, "\n"))] = 0;   /* trim \n saving length */
    
    /* trim remaining whitespace */
    while (len && isspace ((unsigned char)s[len - 1])) {
        len--;
    }
    s[len] = 0;   /* nul-terminate at len */
    
    return len;   /* return new len */
}

int main()
{
    char    *buff = NULL;
    size_t  sizeAllocated = 0;
    ssize_t numCh = 0;
    
    fputs ("Begining!!\n> ", stdout);   /* no conversion, fputs() is fine */
    
    /* validate EVERY input function */
    if ((numCh = getline(&buff, &sizeAllocated, stdin)) == -1) {
        fputs ("error: during getline read.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf ("buff '%s' (numCh: %zu)\n", buff, numCh);
    numCh = trim (buff);
    printf ("\nbuff '%s' (numCh: %zu)\n", buff, numCh);
    
    free (buff);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Sentence with 10 additional trailing spaces:

```
$ ./bin/getline-trimws
Begining!!
> my dog   has fleas
buff 'my dog   has fleas
' (numCh: 29)

buff 'my dog   has fleas' (numCh: 18)
```

An empty line:

```
$ ./bin/getline-trimws
Begining!!
>
buff '
' (numCh: 1)

buff '' (numCh: 0)
```

User generating a manual `EOF` <kbd>Ctrl + d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> on windows):

```
$ ./bin/getline-trimws
Begining!!
> error: during getline read.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

`getline` reads the newline character if there's space in the buffer passed to it.
So you need to look at removing `\n` as well. But you can use `isspace` so that `trim` can handle other whitespace characters too.

Here's a modified version:

```
int trim (char *s)
{
    size_t i = strlen(s);
    if (i == 0) return 0;
    while(isspace((unsigned char)s[i-1])) {
            i--;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;    
}
```

Since `strlen` returns `size_t`, that should be used for `i` - `int` may not be able to hold all possible `size_t` values.